# Disable building and running tests for all Haskell dependencies in a Nix build

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

Disabling the testsuite for my own cabal project is easy with `cabal2nix`, just supply `--no-check`. What about my project's dependencies? How can I disable compiling and running their testuites while building them?

Overriding each dependency (recursively!) with `noCheck = false` seems tedious. Is there some kind of overlay mechanism available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed! To change something recursively for all packages, you can override the thing that generates all packages, and that's `haskellPackages.mkDerivation`. So this is doable with a Haskell package overlay like this:

```
hself: hsuper: {
  mkDerivation = args: hsuper.mkDerivation (args // {
    doCheck = false;
  });
}
```

You can also override other arguments from [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/c51eaf4398a7c2f82d7d31d217191b06342571dc/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/generic-builder.nix#L12) like this. For example you can disable library profiling builds, which commonly halves the build time:

```
hself: hsuper: {
  mkDerivation = args: hsuper.mkDerivation (args // {
    enableLibraryProfiling = false;
  });
}
```

See [this section](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#miscellaneous-topics) in the manual for more info.

Edit: If you want to use this as a user overlay, you can put the following in `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/haskell-no-check.nix`:

```
self: super: {
  haskell = super.haskell // {
    packageOverrides = hself: hsuper: {
      mkDerivation = args: hsuper.mkDerivation (args // {
        doCheck = false;
      });
    };
  };
}
```

Note that this uses `haskell.packageOverrides`, not the somewhat deprecated `packageOverrides` in `config.nix`.

There are other ways of doing it, but I think in this case this is the best because it applies the change to all Haskell package sets.  Unfortunately due to how overriding works, this would clear previous `packageOverrides`, which often isn't a problem, but can be. If you need to persist previous ones, then you can do this:

```
self: super: {
  haskell = super.haskell // {
    packageOverrides = super.lib.composeExtensions super.haskell.packageOverrides
      (hself: hsuper: {
        mkDerivation = args: hsuper.mkDerivation (args // {
          doCheck = false;
        });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds exactly what I'm looking for! How would I put this in an overlay like `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/haskell-packages.nix`? I see that the expressions you wrote would probably be arguments to `packageOverrides`. But IIUC, that's kind of deprecated in favor of overlays.